# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in Material-ui Pickers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Whenever I have installed `@material-ui/pickers` then I have a show this following error. even I also have updated the `@material-ui/core@4.9.5` please Suggest Solutions.

**TypeError: Object(...) is not a function**

```
Module../node_modules/@material-ui/pickers/esm/Wrapper-241966d7.js
D:/EdysorCode/consultant-panel/consultant/node_modules/@material-ui/pickers/esm/Wrapper-241966d7.js:27
  24 | var DIALOG_WIDTH = 310;
  25 | var DIALOG_WIDTH_WIDER = 325;
  26 | var VIEW_HEIGHT = 305;
> 27 | var useStyles = makeStyles(function (theme) {
  28 |   return {
  29 |     staticWrapperRoot: {
  30 |       overflow: 'hidden',
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I also tryed two different peer libraries (luxon and date-fns) but the same error shows up both times.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of material-ui/core are you using?

According to this issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1025, you're probably using an old version of material-ui/core that is not compatible with the latest material-ui/pickers package.

As stated in the README on github: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers#readme

> Note that this package requires @material-ui/core v4. It will not work with the old v3.